# Insert Into statement using arrays in Delphi isn't working

Tags: sql, delphi, ms-access

So I am doing a Delphi 7 project for school that requires me to integrate SQL with a Delphi program. I am using Microsoft access as my database. I am trying to use arrays of string in a insert into statement, but for some reason i constantly get    Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement. My insert code is :

```
ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;                     
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO ' + IntToStr(o) + ' (' + column[t] + ')');
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('VALUES ("' + Stats[t] + '")');  
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('WHERE No = "' + Stats[1] + '" ');                            
ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;
```

`o` is a number that should indicate the table name, `column[t]` is the column that i want `Stats[t]` to appear in.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: `Inttostr` ? is that table name?

Comment: Instead of writing the SQL directly (which is hard to debug), create the query as a temporary string and inspect that with the debugger. Once you see what the generated string looks like, you may be able to solve the problem yourself. As things stand we have no idea what Stats, and column are or look like.

Comment: **0** is not **valid** `table name`

Comment: Once you get it working, start reading on 'parameters'.

Comment: Yeah , & you should use **Parameters** `ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('Param').Value:=value;`.

Comment: @Sami, *"0 is not valid table name"* - there is no such limit in ms-access

Comment: @kobik Can you rename table to '0' ? is that the good way ?

Comment: @Sami, "Can you rename table to '0' ?" - In access you can. "is that the good way?" - no. I would not use that as table name.

Comment: @Sami It seems to me `o` (small letter 'o') is a variable holding an integer. Whether it is good practice to call your tables '1234', is an other question.

Comment: That's my point ,never use numbers as table name

Answer (score 4):

You can not use `WHERE` with an `INSERT` statement.

[SQL INSERT INTO Statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp)

[INSERT INTO Statement (Microsoft Access SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208861(v=office.12).aspx)

For best practice learn how to use [Parameters in Queries](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Using_Parameters_in_Queries)

Answer (score 1):

To insert to table :

```
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('Col1').Value:=Va1;
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('Col2').Value:=Va2;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO YourTable Values(:Col1,:Col2)';
ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;
```

**Note:**

> You **can't** use `WHERE` clause in `INSERT INTO` Statment.
>
> It is better to rename your table ,if the name is a number.

Comment: You should assign the parameter values *after* you assign the SQL text.